# How i can connect backend Crud with front end React?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, backend

Hello folks how are you doing? Hope you are doing well. I learned how to create a project where the backend and frontend were in the same project, where in crud codes (create, update, post and delete) you always finished with res.render("name of the view") and some variables with sql connections.

So my question is, how i can connect this with React in another project? For example, res.render("page from react").

The only thing i did until now was connect data base from back to React with an api, but i don't know how to do it with CRUD.

Here is an example of what im telling:

```
 create: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            let categoria = await db.Category.findAll();
            return res.render("products/crearProyectos", { categorias: categoria });
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            res.send(error);
        }
    },

save: async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let data = req.body;
        let file = req.files;
        let user = await db.User.findByPk(req.session.user.id)

        let projectToCreate = { 
            nombre: String(data.nombre),
            ubicacion: String(data.ubicacion),
            contribucion_actual: 0,
            contribucion_final: parseInt(data.precioFinal),
            texto: String(data.texto),
            fecha_inicial: String(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)),
            fecha_limite: data.fechaProyecto,
            usuario_id: user.id,
            categoria_id: parseInt(data.categoria)
        }

        let projectCreated = await db.Proyect.create(projectToCreate);
           
        let imagenes = [];
        
        Array.from(file).forEach(img => {
            imagenes.push(img.filename);
        })

        let imagenesCreated = await imagenes.forEach(img => {  
            db.Image.create({
                url_imagen: "/"+ data.nombre +"/" + img,
                proyecto_id: projectCreated.id
        })
    });
    
            
    return res.redirect("/proyecto/contribucion/" + projectCreated.id) 
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.send(error);
    }
},
```

From now on thanks for all :)

Comment: What do you use on the backend side?

Comment: I'm using express. Here you have all my dependecies:

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "^6.12.5",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.3.0"
  },

Comment: `how i can connect this with React in another project` Did you mean the view is placed on another server or what? `Here is an example of what im telling` You are telling what? You don't know how to do it with CRUD, but the example shows a working example working with CRUD.

Comment: Ok, what im saying its that i don´t know how to connect the controller with a view from react, my frontside with react its in another project, so my question it, how i can connect the controller with the react view from the other project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.